# How to associate a keyfile with a site in FileZilla

Tags: server, ssh, ftp, sftp

Initially, I had a problem with creating a site within FileZilla as I needed to use a private key to log in to the server, but there wasn't any option listed for logging in with a keyfile. As per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697439/how-to-connect-to-sftp-in-filezilla-using-private-key) I was able to add a keyfile, but I noticed that the site that I created originally hadn't been saved. When I went to create another site, I figured that I just needed to use "normal" as the authentication type, but after selecting "ok", the type changed to "ask for password" for some reason.

The problem is that I don't have the keyfile associated with that site, even though the keyfile is stored in the system so when I log back in, it still asks me for my password. Given that I'm having to retroactively add the keyfile, how can I associate the keyfile with each site that I create?

Comment: Latest FileZilla has feature to specify Key-File for each site entry.
Please follow this [FileZilla Forum](https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=18084)

Comment: You will probaby have to convert the open ssh key to .ppk with [putty-tools](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=putty-tools) first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, the previously mentioned is not true. I was too naive that things can work out together.

In FileZilla you have to add the key using, menu *Edit* → *Preferences* → *SFTP*, as you did. Or make sure the key is in your `ssh-agent` before starting FileZilla (`ssh-add -l` should list the key).

You account in *Site Manager* has to have the *"Normal"* logon type with an empty password and the key should be tried automatically.

Comment: I added the ```config``` file in the ```\.ssh``` directory and then back in the site manager in  filezilla I selected "Interactive" as the logon type, as that one was the option where a password prompt wasn't required. After selecting "connect", it seems to have connected to the server; however, I'm not sure if the keyfile was even used for authentication How can I tell if the keyfile was used?

Comment: It seems to be working now